# Поиск отдельных частей графа в спискe смежности

Tags: php, графы, связи

Есть граф составленный из списка смежностей:

```
Узел Связность
A    B
B    A
C
D
E    G
F    G
G    F,E
```

и представляется из себя посути разорванный граф:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Записав данный граф в массив получил:

```
Array
(
        [A] => Array
        (
                [0] => B
        )

        [B] => Array
        (
                [0] => A
        )

        [C] => Array
        (
        )

        [D] => Array
        (
        )

        [E] => Array
        (
                [0] => G
        )

        [F] => Array
        (
                [0] => G
        )

        [G] => Array
        (
                [0] => F
                [1] => E
        )
    )
```

Подскажите, как из входных данных получить отдельные части графа (на картинке обвел красным):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и получить на выходе примерно такой массив:

```
Array
(
        [0] => Array
        (
                [0] => A
                1 => B
        )
```

`[1] => Array
    (
            [0] => C
    )

    [2] => Array
    (
            [0] => D
    )

    [3] => Array
    (
            [0] => G
            [0] => F
            [1] => E
    )
)`

Подскажите  алгоритм, или хотябы в какую сторону копать?

Answer (score 3):

Вот вам алгоритм:

1. Берёте первую непосещённую вершину графа.
2. Поиском в [глубину](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA_%D0%B2_%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83) или в [ширину](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA_%D0%B2_%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83) обходите все вершины, достижимые из неё.
3. Каждую посещённую вершину (включая начальную) помечаете как (простите за тавтологию) посещённую.
4. Если посещены не все вершины - goto 1.

Для этого алгоритма будет удобно завести отдельный массив, в котором будут отмечаться посещения вершин. Помечать в нём вершины как посещённые лучше всего числами, отображающими порядковый номер "острова", к которому относится вершина. Номер "острова" будет увеличиваться на 1 в п. 1. Также при помощи такого массива будет удобно отслеживать момент окончания работы алгоритма - как только все вершины в нём будут помечены как посещённые, алгоритм закончил свою работу.